# Proof that $f$ is injective iff $\bigcap_{i\in I} f(A_i) = f( \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$ for every $(A_i)_{i\in I}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I think I have a proof by contradiction of the following result but I am not sure about it.

> Show that $f$ is injective iff $\bigcap_{i\in I} f(A_i) = f( \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$ for every $(A_i)_{i\in I}$.

This is my first contact with actual mathematical theory, and it has always been my biggest knowledge gap as my actual field of study(physics) relies mostly on just applying math more than really understanding it, so I can say it has been a pretty rough first contact...

My try is as follows:
Assuming f(x) is not injective, then,
$ \exists x \land x' \in X; x \neq x'; f(x) = f(x')$
Taking $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I}A_i \land x' \in A_i$, but, 
$x' \notin \bigcap_{i \in I}A_i \Rightarrow f(x) \in f(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i) \land f(x') \notin f(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i)$, however, $f(x) = f(x')$.
Hence, being a contradiction!

Comment: It seems that you have two questions here. You should write your second question in a different post. Also, you're new here. What have you tried?

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't want to create too many posts, sorry, I will fix it right away, thank you. As for my attempt, I will also edit my post to include my partial resolution, one moment, as I believe it would be hard to expose it here.

Comment: Added my previous attempt, sorry for late response, this is also my first contact with MathJax, it took a little while to write(and fix it. A few times...).

Comment: @GeorgeN.Missailidis "Improving formatting" Actually, you are actively deteriorating the formatting (ever heard of not mixing mathematical symbols and plain English?). This is not the first time your edits are detrimental to a page, you might wish to stop.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Please be more careful before accepting edits that are actually detrimental to some given post.

Comment: @Shailesh Please be more careful before accepting edits that are actually detrimental to some given post.

Comment: k sorry about that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your solution, it is not clear how you can choose your $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$. Here are some hints;

**Hint 1:** Assume that $f:X \to Y$ is not injective. Then, as you've correctly pointed out, $\exists x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $x_1 \neq x_2$ and  $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Let $A_1 = \{x_1\}$ and let $A_2 = \{x_2\}$. Then $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. However, what is $f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$?

**Hint 2:** Assume that $f:X \to Y$ is injective. We want to show that $\bigcap_{i \in I} f(A_i) = f(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)$.

*Step 1*. First we show that $\bigcap_{i \in I} f(A_i) \subseteq f(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)$. Let $b \in \bigcap_{i \in I} f(A_i)$. Then, we know that there is a $c \in X$ such that $f(c) = b$.  By injectivity (*why?*), $c \in \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$. Then, $f(c) \in f(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$ and this implies that $b \in f(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$.

*Step 2*. Now, we show the other inclusion. Let $b \in f(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i)$. It's up to you to show that $b \in f(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$. This is the easy direction.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for, I'm really grateful for your help, I will definitely be able to solve it now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"Show that
 f(x) is injective $\Leftrightarrow  \bigcap_{i _\in I} (f(A_i)) = f( \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$"

First see that we always have the following

$$  \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i\subset A_i~~~\forall ~i \implies f( \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)\subset \bigcap_{i _\in I} (f(A_i)) $$

so the problem reduces to

f(x) is injective $\Leftrightarrow  \bigcap_{i _\in I} (f(A_i)) \subset f( \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$

> Which can again be reduce to the following 
>   f(x) is injective $\Leftrightarrow f(A) \cap f(B) \subset f( A\cap B).$"
>   Where A and B can be replaced by $A_i$ and $A_j$ respectively.

Now let prove our last claim.

> Assume f(x) is injective

Then let $z\in(A) \cap f(B) $ i.e $\{z\in f(A)  \implies \exists a\in A :f(a) = z \}$ and $\{z\in f(B)  \implies \exists b\in B :f(b) = z \}$  Thus, $f(a) = z= f(b)$. But $f$ is injective we then have $a=b \in A \cap B $ therefore $z=f(a)= f(b)\in  $z\in f(A\cap B) $. hence, $f(A) \cap f(B) \subset f( A\cap B).$

> Conversely, Assume $f(A) \cap f(B) \subset f( A\cap B).$
>   let prove that f is injective. Let $a$ and $b$ bet two elements in the domain of $f$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. We set 
>   $$A =\{a\}\qquad\land\qquad B=\{b\}$$
>   by Asumption, we have,

$$\{f(a)=f(b)\}=f(\{a\}) \cap f(\{b\}) \subset f( \{a\}\cap \{b\}).$$
but 
$$\{a\}\cap \{b\}= \begin{cases}\{a=b\}& if~~ a=b \\ ∅ &if ~~a\neq b\end{cases}$$

The only option we have is $a=b$ since $f(a) = f(b)\inf( \{a\}\cap \{b\}) $ that is $f( \{a\}\cap \{b\})$ is a nonempty set and we know that $f($∅$) =$∅ $\therefore f$ is an injective application.